# Error using .reserve() to reserve space for a vector

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, declaration

I am attempting to reserve memory for a med_array vector as seen below

```
vector <int> med_array = {};
med_array.reserve(50000);
MedianFinder();
void addNum(int num);
double findMedian();
vector<int> get_array();
void print_array();
```

However, I get an error stating:

```
medianfinderheader.h:10:4: error: 'med_array' does not name a type
   10 |    med_array.reserve(50000);
```

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Is this code inside a function or in the global scope?

Comment: Compiles for me - live - https://godbolt.org/z/djv4EjMfT.  Please check that your [mcve] reproduces the error.

Comment: I suspect that you actually want to place this line in a `MedianFinder` constructor

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out .reserve needs to be run inside a function I can't define in the class header like I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the error message, these lines:

```
vector <int> med_array = {};
med_array.reserve(50000);
```

are in a (global) namespace where you may place only declarations. But this line:

```
med_array.reserve(50000);
```

is not a declaration. So the compiler issues the error. That is, the compiler tries to interpret the line as a declaration, but the name `med_array` is not a type specifier.

From the C++ 20 Standard (9.8 Namespaces)

> 1 **A namespace is an optionally-named declarative region**. The name of a namespace can be used to access entities declared in that namespace; that is, the members of the namespace. Unlike other declarative regions, the definition of a namespace can be split over several parts of one or more translation units.

Pay attention to that this declaration:

```
vector <int> med_array = {};
```

can be written simpler, like:

```
vector <int> med_array;
```

Or, you could initially declare the vector with 50000 elements, like:

```
vector <int> med_array( 50'000 );
```